# How to get the border under the textView in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I already know how to get the border around the `TextView`.
But how do I get the border **under** the `TextView` in android?

Comment: Use a View under text view with line appreance . Or you can make a drawable with border only at bottom .

Comment: What border? Please explain in more detail

Comment: @floreich lets take Whatsapp there is a think border between contact to contact .,

Comment: Don't suggest me to make that border color as background image for entire layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Create a drawable resource file 
Step 2: Name it underline 
Step 3 : add this code in the underline file

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Step 3 : set this as a background in which ever Textview you use like

```
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/underline"
   android:text="Your text"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```